# Pylons custom authorizer with Authkit?

Tags: python, authentication, pylons, authkit

How do i setup authkit for more authorizers?  I want to give certain users admin rights, but only for their own page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/authentication-and-authorization.html#authkit

What do you mean by 'admin rights, but only for their own page'? You mean that user could, for example view other user profiles and edit his own profile?
In this case you should check what information should be shown to user and what actions (s)he could perform by yourself.